# WSL service docker starts but no internet

Tags: docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I start running WSL and if I ping google.com, I receive packages just fine. When I run `sudo service docker start`, it runs fine. But thereafter, when I ping google.com, I do not receive packages. Does anyone know why?

```
#/etc/resolv.conf

nameserver 8.8.8.8

#/etc/resolv.conf

[automount]
options = "metadata"

[network]
generateResolvConf = false
```

I tried restarting both WSL and the computer but it does not help. I also tried this suggestion too: [WSL2 - No internet connectivity. DNS Issues(Temporary failure in name resolution) #6404](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6404)

Comment: can you provide results of `netstat -r` ( op `ip r s `) before and after docker start ? (edit your question, do not provide it in comment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem was the hyper-v extension.
I need to torn on, and it work fine.

Comment: **YES!**  This was my problem, too: WSL2 networking dead in the water, couldn't ping out of the VM at all, only 127.0.0.1.  This of course broke DNS and other things like package installation.  **To fix:** TLDR: in elevated PowerShell, do `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Hyper-V -All`  as seen [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v).  Another reference that looks slower is [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/step-by-step-enabling-hyper-v-for-use-on-windows-10/ba-p/267945).

Comment: Was woried it would break WSL2 but all went well. Activated HyperV and then `systemctl docker start` didn't break connectivity inside the shell anymore. Don't know why it started to bug anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Docker somehow uses the same network than WSL2. This can cause conflicts.
To fix this issue you should explicitly tell docker to use a different network.

Add this to your `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

```
{
    "bip" : "10.10.0.1/16"
}
```

Note that I **did not** change the auto-generation of `resolv.conf` as in some networks, there is a forced proxy - and one cannot access public DNS servers.

Credits:

- https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4285#issuecomment-1180567785
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/74984134/873282